# Errors while integrating bootstrap template in Django

Tags: python, django

I was trying to integrate the bootstrap template in my Django project. I have integrated it but I am having an error in the URL.
The following is the error I have:
[image]

Codes in template:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <div class="shop-cat-box">
         <a href="{% url 'fertilizer-name' %}"><img class="img" src="{% static 'images/cyp/3.png' %}" alt="" /></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

In URL:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', findex, name='fertilizer-name'),
    path('fertilizer/',predict_chances,name='submit_prediction'),
    path('fertilizer/results/',view_results,name='results'),
]
```

Comment: Can you share the views.py to see how you are reversing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you’re including the `urls.py` in the project with a namespace. In that case, the reverse would be `namespace:view` name. Try that in your template inside the url tag and see if that works.

So, i think in your case, in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'fertilizer:fertilizer-name' %}"><img class="img" src="{% static 'images/cyp/3.png' %}" alt="" /></a>
```